# cxf and spring MVC : No service was found

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, cxf

I have spring application, in which I use org.apache.cxf for soap and spring MVC for displayng some pages.
My `web.xml` contains two servlets :`CXFServlet and mvc-dispatcher`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I has been used `@ResponseBody` in my controller everything was fine.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
@ResponseBody
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome() {       
        return "hello" ;
    }
}
```

but then i was needed to use jsp I have to use the following

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "hello");
        return new ModelAndView("hello") ;
    }
}
```

and  when I request `http://localhost:8080/hello` I get "No service was found" instead of  "hello"

I found that if I delete following from web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

my controller works fine.

Answer (score 5):

The Servlet container you are using is matching CXFServlet instead of mvc-dispatcher for the URI `http://localhost:8080/hello`, resulting in your request being sent to CXFServlet, and the error message "No service was found" being returned by CXFServlet.  To quote the Servlet 3.0 spec,

> Versions of this specification prior to 2.5 made use of these mapping
>   techniques as a suggestion rather than a requirement, allowing servlet
>   containers to each have their different schemes for mapping client
>   requests to servlets.

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

You will likely need to configure you CXFServlet mapping to something else, e.g.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You might want to mention the container (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.) that you are using, as there could also be a bug preventing this from working correctly.